# Cannot clear a TextView since I added a TextWatcher?

Tags: java, android, textview, textwatcher

I have a simple golf scorecard app I'm developing. I have 9 textviews for now in which you enter a score hole by hole. When the score is entered the TextView background goes green if below par, red if above and white if even. IU have done this with TextWatchers.

I have a clear all Fields class, which clears all the textviews which always worked. But since I added the textwatchers for the scores my clear all textViews has stopped working. The program crashes.

This is my clear all TextView Code,

public class clearButtonListner implements OnClickListener {

```
private Activity activity;

public clearButtonListner(Activity activity){

    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    TextView et1 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore1);
    TextView et2 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore2);
    TextView et3 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore3);
    TextView et4 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore4);
    TextView et5 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore5);
    TextView et6 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore6);
    TextView et7 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore7);
    TextView et8 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore8);
    TextView et9 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore9);
    TextView ettotal = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextTotalScore);


    et1.setText("");
    et2.setText("");
    et3.setText("");
    et4.setText("");
    et5.setText("");
    et6.setText("");
    et7.setText("");
    et8.setText("");
    et9.setText("");
    ettotal.setText("");

}
```

}

Example of one of my textWatchers,
public class textWatcher1 implements TextWatcher{

```
private Activity activity;

public textWatcher1(Activity activity){

    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



    int p1 = 5;
    // Create my TextViews
    TextView et1 = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.EditTextScore1);

    int s1 = (int)(Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()));

    if(s1 < p1){

    et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    

    }


    else if(s1 > p1){

    et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);      

    }

    else if(s1 == p1){

    et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);        

    }
}
```

}

Any help would be great. The app crashes with throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid int: \"" + s + "\""); Exception.

Comment: The app crashes with which Exception?

Comment: Yes,     throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid int: \"" + s + "\"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because after erasing all your `EditTexts` with that `Button` click, your  `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` callback is called. It is expecting a some content on your `EditText` but finds nothing, thus throwing that `Exception`, in `parseInt()`.

You just have to add a condition for that code to execute, this is, only if the length of the text is bigger that 0. That way you will prevent the callback from making your app crash after clearing the `EditTexts`.

So, just add this line inside `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`:

```
 if(s.length()>0){

    //your existing code

 }
```

I advise you to only fill those `EditTexts` with content that is convertible to a number, or you will get that `Exception` again.